# What's the difference between static and dynamic scoping in this exercise?

Tags: pseudocode, scoping

I get confused when dealing with the static scope and dynamic scope, and for this pseudocode I have to find both. For both I believe it should print out: 9 4 2 3 however, I'm not entirely sure. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
g: integer

procedure B(a: integer)
    x: integer

    x := a X a
    R(1)

procedure A(n: integer)
    g := n

procedure R(m: integer)
    write_integer(x)
    x /:= 2       -- integer division
    if x > 1
        R(m + 1)
    else
        A(m)

procedure main()  -- entry point
    B(3)
    write_integer(g)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your language were statically scoped, then the variable `x` would be local only to the function `B`, and it would not be visible outside `B`.

However, your language is dynamically scoped: The first time the control flow passes over the line `x: integer`, the variable `x` is now *globally accessible*.

So, here's the order of events:

- `B(3)` assigns `x := 9`
- `R(1)` writes `9` and assigns `x = 4` and calls `R(2)`
- `R(2)` writes `4` and assigns `x = 2` and calls `R(3)`
- `R(3)` writes `2` and assignx `x = 1` and calls `A(3)`
- `A(3)` assigns `g = 3`
- `write_integer(g)` prints `3`.